# Select coordinates without a given z ? by using KDTREE

Tags: python, scripting

Would it be possible to use the KDTree without taking into account the z-coordinate? According to the documentation, find(co) necessarily requires a vector (x,y,z) but what interests me is to find the nearest point in (x,y) without taking into account the z (which may really vary my result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Arbitrarily set z**

Using the example from https://docs.blender.org/api/master/mathutils.kdtree.html#module-mathutils.kdtree

Test script, find all verts within 1 local blender unit in mesh projected to `z = 0` plane, from the 3d cursor projected to same plane.  Adjust `z` to suit.

```
import mathutils

# set the z of the xyplane
z = 0
# create a kd-tree from a mesh
from bpy import context
obj = context.object
mesh = obj.data
size = len(mesh.vertices)
kd = mathutils.kdtree.KDTree(size)

for v in mesh.vertices:
    kd.insert((v.co.x, v.co.y, z), v.index)

kd.balance()


# 3d cursor relative to the object data
co_find = context.scene.cursor.location @ obj.matrix_world.inverted()
# set the same to find nearest projected to that plane.
co_find.z = z 

for co, index, dist in kd.find_range(co_find, 1):
    print(f"Vert[{index}].co[:] = {mesh.vertices[index].co} (xy dist = {dist})")
```

[image]

Test run cursor location in image, selects the vertices of leading edge of cube as seen from camera in default scene.

```
Vert[1].co = (1.0, -1.0, -1.0) (xy dist = 0.030091779306530952)
Vert[5].co = (0.9999993443489075, -1.0000005960464478, 1.0) (xy dist = 0.030092377215623856)
```